# Select elements where id doesn't partialy match user typed string

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to build a custom filter system where elements that don't match what the user has typed (will be a search on the id of each element for match).  It will consists of the following:

TextBox - this is where the user would start typing to match the id on the data set. Only matched results will be visible, while non-matches will be hidden. If the box is empty or cleared, all results will be displayed.

Data-Set - This will be the data in the form of divs or table rows. Each parent `td` or `div` will have a unique id.

Following is a sample version of the data-set :

```
<table>
<tr id=".com"><td>.com</td></tr>
<tr id=".com.au"><td>.com</td></tr>
<tr id=".ca"><td>.com</td></tr>
<tr id=".au"><td>.com</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using the above example, here is an example of expected results :

User types 'om' - Results in (showing the css applied, however jQuery.hide() will work fine. This is to display the difference only) :

```
<table>
<tr id=".com"><td>.com</td></tr>
<tr id=".ca" style="visibility: collapse"><td>.ca</td></tr>
<tr id=".au" style="visibility: collapse"><td>.au</td></tr>
<tr id=".com.au"><td>.com.au</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using `<input type="text" id="search">`, what is the efficient way to achieve this objective using jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
var inputValue = $('#search').val();
jQuery('tr:not([id*="' + inputValue + '"])').hide();
```

This is a combination of the [attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector and the [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

Comment: So thats how that is uses.  So nice and purrrty.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Following will work based on any method of user input

```
var $rows = $('#tableID tr');// cache rows to avoid constant DOM searching
$('#search').on('input', function(){
  var val = this.value;
  if(!val){
    // show all when input is cleared
    $rows.show();
  }else{
    // hide all then filter ones to show
    $rows.hide().filter(function(){
       return this.id.indexOf(val) >-1;
     }).show()
  }

});
```

Comment: This is also very nice.  In my case, caching the rows might be a problem due to the amount of data contained inside them in total, but thankfully the dom tree is a short trip to the element start which I intend to work with.

Comment: quite the opposite , caching the rows will be far more performant if you have a lot of them. The other approach requires a lot of individual searches which is expensive

Comment: The row count isn't that large.  The content inside each row is about 60kb.  Will try both ways, just I would like to be friendly to the memory use of the users computer :)

Comment: What's in the rows is irrelevant ... it's the repetitive searches through all those rows you want to avoid. Much faster searching through a cached object that already contains only the wanted elements

Comment: This works, but I have an issue where it is hiding all trs inside nested tables.  Is there a way to tweak this so it filters only on the parent table ?

Comment: sure... add children selector

Comment: How would that be to exclude it   `table > tbody > tr:not('table > tbody > tr > td > table')`   ?   basically, i need it to exclude nested content from it's search.  it would likely speed it up a lot as well.

Comment: Simpler ... `#tableID > tbody > tr`.Selector  `>` denotes only direct children

Comment: I am using  `tbody > tr` .  The nested tables do not contain `tbody`, however their `tr` is still being filtered on.

Comment: some browsers will create tbody if none exists. Using direct children of main table will work.

Comment: i will try with full path from parent table and see if that prevents the sub hiding.  That's what was happening, it's still kind of laggy.  Only 637 records, but at least it filters on it which was the objective of this :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but here's a different approach using `indexOf()`:

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
  $('#mySearchTbl').find('tr').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    if(val && tr.attr('id').indexOf(val) <= 0) {
        tr.css('visibility', 'collapse');
    }   else {
        tr.css('visibility', 'inherit');
    }
  })
});
```

[And a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8uw2091/3/), if you want to see it in action. Just another way of handling string searching without pesky `RegEx`.

**EDIT**
I see Charlie beat me to the punch, and with nice use of the `filter()` method, so yeah I'd go with that one for a more reusable script as that code can be ran without jQuery, just with different selectors.

[filter() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[indexOf() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)